# Add kernel boot parameter from package

Tags: grub2, packaging

I'm creating my own debian package which has to add a kernel boot parameter when installed in order to work properly.

The place to have this is `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.

My current approach to simply create the file (my package was the only one doing this) worked until today... Now it is seems that `mdadm` and my package both try to create that file.

So my question is: Is there a best practice for package maintainers to permanently add a kernel boot parameter?

Comment: In 16.04, there is `/etc/default/grub.d`.

Comment: it's there in 14.04, too. But as far as I understood, the scripts in there read from `/etc/default/grub` and add lines to `/boot/grub/grub2.cfg`.

Comment: I'm talking of `/etc/default/grub.d`, not `/etc/grub.d`, they are different.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... I've read your comment to quickly... It looks like it might be in earlier versions, too. I'll try that...